# XML XSLT conversion. Three environments, three different line counts using Oracle's xml util

Tags: xml, linux, oracle, xslt

I'm fairly new at xml conversion using xslt.  I've been using Oracle 11g's xml tool in order to play with it in Linux.  I have run into a snag though.  I have a fairly big xml file that when I flatten it using my xslt conversion I get three different results (record number wise) on three different boxes using the exact same input xml and xslt as well as same oracle version.

On one I get 349,227 records every single time
On another I get 262,144 every single time
On the last I get 131,072 every single time

I get no errors and the flat files look identical aside from the missing records (assuming the first one is the "truth" file).  I'm trying to figure out if there's a config somewhere where I may need to increase some memory or page parameters or something which would explain why they stop?  Return code is 0 and I'm a little confused.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Kypt, it is impossible to answer your question without sample data, code, and expected (or in your case, unexpected) results. Please see [ask] for how to ask a question.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you chose oracle's XDK tools? As far as I know, they haven't been further developed after the Sun acquisition which happened in 2010. Even then, they had been neglected: Oracle started implementing XSLT 2.0 (which came out in 2007) but never finished the job.

Comment: Brian, thing is I was under the impression this may be a config issue somewhere but looking at the different boxes there seems to be slightly different versions between them all.  I'm installing the "truth" oracle version on one of the boxes where I got a lot less records and trying to figure if maybe it's a bug.  I'll let you guys know.  As for the Oracle XDK tools being used, I'm replacing a process that currently uses it and trying to mimic it to avoid complications but there's a chance that by the end of the day today I'll be using Saxon.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the oracle client version. Once I updated the client from 11.1.0.6.0 to 12.1.0.2 and issue went away. I'm now getting all the records I should.  I'm not sure if there was a bug back on 11 for big files but it seems it's all resolved.